# MVVM Searchbar Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am trying to implement a searchbar using MVVM in Xamarin.forms. so far I have managed to borrow some code from around the internet and it seems to do go through the motions of the search. the only issue is I don't know what code to put in the command.

I would like the search bar to search recipeNames from a list of Recipes. this information is all stored on a local database and displayed using an observable collection.

please can you help me work it out.

XAML

```
<SearchBar x:Name="SearchBar" 
               Placeholder="Search" 
               SearchCommand="{Binding SearchCommand}" 
               SearchCommandParameter="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference SearchBar}}"
               Text="{Binding SearchText, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <SearchBar.Behaviors>
            <local:TextChangedBehavior />
        </SearchBar.Behaviors>
    </SearchBar>
    <ListView x:Name="ListViewItems"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Recipes}"
          IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
          Refreshing="ListViewItems_Refreshing"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRecipe}">
```

Text changed Behaviour

```
    class TextChangedBehavior: Behavior<Xamarin.Forms.SearchBar>
{
    protected override void OnAttachedTo(Xamarin.Forms.SearchBar bindable)
        {
            base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
            bindable.TextChanged += Bindable_TextChanged;
        }

        protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Xamarin.Forms.SearchBar bindable)
        {
            base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);
            bindable.TextChanged -= Bindable_TextChanged;
        }

        private void Bindable_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((Xamarin.Forms.SearchBar)sender).SearchCommand?.Execute(e.NewTextValue);
        }

    }
```

and viewModel

```
public class RecipeListViewModel : ObservableCollection<Recipe>
{
    private ObservableCollection<Recipe> Recipes {get; set;}
    public INavigation Navigation { get; internal set; }
    public ICommand NewAddPage { get; protected set; }
    public RecipeListViewModel(INavigation navigation)
    {
        this.Navigation = navigation;
        Recipes = new ObservableCollection<Recipe>();
        this.NewAddPage = new Command(async () => await CreateNewAddPage());
        Init();
    }

    // Gets all recipes from the database and adds them to the observable collection
    private void Init()
    {
        var enumarator = App.RecipeDbcontroller.GetRecipe();
        if (enumarator == null)
        {
            App.RecipeDbcontroller.SaveRecipe(new Recipe { RecipeName = "Moussaka", Serves = 6, PrepTime = "30", CookTime = "2 Hours", MealType = "Dinner" });

            enumarator = App.RecipeDbcontroller.GetRecipe();
        }
        while (enumarator.MoveNext())
        {
            //cleans database of all empty records
            if (enumarator.Current.RecipeName == null || enumarator.Current.CookTime == null)
            {
                App.RecipeDbcontroller.DeleteRecipe(enumarator.Current.RecipeID);
            }
            else
                Add(enumarator.Current);
        }
    }


    private ICommand _searchCommand;
    public ICommand SearchCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _searchCommand ?? (_searchCommand = new Command<string>((text) =>
            {
                **// THIS IS WHAT I DON'T KNOW WHAT TO DO**
            }));
        }
    }

    private string _searchText { get; set; }
    public string SearchText
    {
        get { return _searchText; }
        set
        {
            if (_searchText != value)
            {
                _searchText = value;
            }
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

RecipeDatabaseController Class

```
 public RecipeDatabaseController()
        {
            this.database = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().GetConnection();
            this.database.CreateTable<Recipe>();
        }

        //Recipe CRUD
        public IEnumerator<Recipe> GetRecipe()
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                if (database.Table<Recipe>().Count() == 0)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                else
                {
                    return this.database.Table<Recipe>().GetEnumerator();
                }
            }
        }

        public IEnumerator<Recipe> GetRecipeBySearchTerm(text)
        {
            var enumarator = GetRecipe();
            lock (locker)
            {
                while (enumarator.MoveNext)
                {
                    if(enumarator.Current.RecipeName.Contains(text)
                        return this.
                }
            }
        }

        public int SaveRecipe(Recipe recipe)
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                if (recipe.RecipeID != 0)
                {
                    this.database.Update(recipe);
                    return recipe.RecipeID;
                }
                else
                {
                    return this.database.Insert(recipe);
                }
            }
        }

        public int DeleteRecipe(int Id)
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                return this.database.Delete<Recipe>(Id);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I think you already know what to do, search your local database using the user input (text parameter inside the command func) and add/remove into variable `recipes` which is observablecollection. Also your listview itemsource should be ItemsSource="{Binding recipes}"

Comment: Thanks dude, What would that look like in code?

Comment: also when I set the binding to recipes it doesn't show the list

Comment: Your recipe is `private` make that `public`

Comment: `App.RecipeDbcontroller.GetRecipe();` what is this? is this fetching all the recipe?

Comment: yes It gets all the recipes from the database

Comment: I have written this into the code  enumarator = App.RecipeDbcontroller.GetRecipe();  return _searchCommand ?? (_searchCommand = new Command<string>((text) =>
                {
                    while (enumarator.MoveNext())
                    {
                        if (enumarator.Current.RecipeName == text)
                        {

                            recipes.Add(enumarator.Current);
                        }
                    }
                }));
            }
        }

Comment: create new method `App.RecipeDbcontroller.GetRecipeBySearchTerm(text);` this method can be called inside the command and set the `recipes`

Comment: It doesn't work, because the binding still doesn't work

Comment: is your `recipes` public? not private

Comment: `App.RecipeDbcontroller.GetRecipe();` what is the return type?

Comment: why are you enumerating ? use linq

Comment: yes recipes is public not private.

Comment: the return type is                                                                                           return this.database.Table<Recipe>().GetEnumerator();

Comment: I don't know how to use linq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

right so the search command ought to look like this.

```
public ICommand SearchCommand => _searchCommand ?? (_searchCommand = new Command<string>((text) =>
{
    if (text.Length >=1)
    {
        Recipes.Clear();
        Init();
        var suggestions = Recipes.Where(c => c.RecipeName.ToLower().StartsWith(text.ToLower())).ToList();
        Recipes.Clear();
        foreach (var recipe in suggestions)
         Recipes.Add(recipe);

    }
    else
    {
        Recipes.Clear();
        Init();
        ListViewVisible = true;
        SuggestionsListViewVisible = false;
    }

}));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Linq;

    //Recipe CRUD
    public IEnumerable<Recipe> GetRecipe()
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            return this.database.Table<Recipe>();
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Recipe> GetRecipeBySearchTerm(string text)
    {
        var recipes = GetRecipe();
        lock (locker)
        {
            return recipes.Where(m => m.RecipeName.ToLower().Contains(text));
        }
    }
```

Add the `using System.Linq` reference

Change those two methods and return `IEnumerable`

Note. `RecipeName` is the property you want to filter your Recipe with.

And your search command as below

```
private ICommand _searchCommand;
public ICommand SearchCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _searchCommand ?? (_searchCommand = new Command<string>((text) =>
        {
            var filteredRecipes = App.RecipeDbcontroller.GetRecipeBySearchTerm(text);

            recipes.Clear();
            foreach(var recipe in filteredRecipes )
                 recipes.Add(recipe);
        }));
    }
}
```

I have not tested this code, so not sure where I might get errors, but you can work out the rest because the logic is given to you

Good luck

Comment: your are a genius thank you. The binding still doesn't work though. I have changed recipes to public and it didn't do anything.

Comment: @JamesPalmer did you add `BindingContext = new RecipeListViewModel ();` in your cs.xaml?

Comment: @JamesPalmer I wouldnt know why binding is not working unless I  run your code on my machine

Comment: yes I did it looks like this BindingContext = new RecipeListViewModel(Navigation);

Comment: Sorry from here I dont know what is happening without debugging your code

Comment: last thing `ItemsSource="{Binding recipes}"` one more thing? did you set the datatemplate in your listview?

Comment: I have added your query and it looks like it crashes the whole app everytime I run it.

Comment: would it be easier not to query the database directly but to query recipes in recipes?

Comment: 09-15 12:14:25.113 E/OpenGLRenderer( 3641): GL error:  Out of memory!
09-15 12:14:25.113 F/OpenGLRenderer( 3641): GL errors! frameworks/base/libs/hwui/renderthread/CanvasContext.cpp:550
09-15 12:14:25.115 F/libc    ( 3641): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 3674 (RenderThread)

Comment: Never seen this error, you can do query on recipes just not efficient but still doable, I seriously dont know whats going on, unless you can give me the project for me to run and find the issue, i cannot help you further, just takes too much time going back and forth good luck

Comment: how would you search an observablecollection?

Comment: right so I fixed the binding problem by adding a {get set} to the global observable collection and adding the recipe ObservableCollection to the Recipe ListView constructor.